# Trouble subclassing UITableViewCell (2 warnings)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, warnings, subclass

Following the documentation on custom cells from a NIB (the Dynamic option), I have this method. (The view itself is not a UITableViewController, but it's hooked up properly.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReusableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (LoadGameCell *)
                  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    loadNibNamed:@"LoadGameCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = loadGameCell;
        self.loadGameCell = nil;
    }

    /*
     cell setup
     */

    return cell;
}
```

The first line in the `if` statement is the bit I'm having trouble with.

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UITableViewCell *' from 'NSArray *'

Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSArray *',
                                expected 'struct UITableViewCell *'
```

No errors/crashes running the app with these warnings, but I'd rather not ignore/suppress them. It'll hurt a whole lot more later on.

If it isn't a direct result of the warnings above, there's another problem. I can't get the method to take views, only labels. (That is, I can customize a label, but not the image view it's sitting next to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation will tell you, `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` returns an array. To access the cell in the NIB (assuming it is the only root-level object in the NIB), call `objectAtIndex:0` on the result of `loadNibNamed:owner:options`.

Comment: I'm useless when it comes to such simple bugs... They're subtle, so I miss them completely. Thanks.